# Multivariate Hypergeometric distribution: Leaving a ball in the urn for each color

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Let's assume I have an Urn experiment with balls colored with $R$ colors and each color has $F$ balls and I draw $M$ balls. $u_r$ denotes the number of $r$-colored balls and $U_r$ the corresponding random variable. Thus I get the probability for a specific colored draw as

\begin{align}
P( U_1 = u_1,\ldots, U_R=u_R) = \frac{ \binom {F}{u_1} \cdot \binom {F}{u_2} \cdot \ldots \cdot \binom {F}{u_R} }{ \binom {R\cdot F}{M} }
\end{align}

But now I introduce the rule that for each $r$ must be $u_r\in\{ 0,\ldots, F-1 \}$. In other words, for each color there must remain at least one ball in the urn.

Does, and if how does, this change the probability?

Currently I wrote for my paper

[image]

where the "weird looking U" are the $u_r$.

Comment: Seemingly some one has asked a similar question recently. I am not sure how the "rule" related to your experiment. One possible thought: just replacing $F$ by $F-1$?

Comment: @BGM: That would change the number of available balls in the urn and thus the likelihood of drawing that color. Lets say I have three white (W) and three black (B) balls (my formula) or I have two white and two black balls. The likelihood should to draw {2W, 1B} should be different for the two szenario, don't you  think?

Comment: No.  You may use Bayes' Rule to verify that the rule can be enforced by removing one ball of each colour from the urn and putting them aside until after the drawing is done with the same probability distribution as if you intervened to force a replacement every time the $F^{\rm th}$ ball of each colour is withdrawn.

Answer (score 0):

You are restricting the possible outcomes by forbidding any where $F$ balls of any colour are withdrawn.

There are various ways to forbid those outcomes.   You can force a complete redraw should one happen, you could insist any time a third ball of any colour are drawn they are redrawn repeatedly until third balls of any colour no longer appear, or you could remove one ball of each colour until the drawing is done.

Each method prohibits the forbidden outcomes without changing the relative probabilities of the restricted outcomes among themselves.  They shall have the same probability distribution. Therefore we can use the last model to evaluate the conditional probability of the event given the outcome is not one of the forbidden events ($\phi$).

$$\therefore \mathsf P(\vec U=\vec u\mid \vec U\notin \phi) ~=~ \dfrac{\prod_{i=1}^R \binom {F-1}{u_i}}{\binom{R(F-1)}{M}}$$

---

> That would change the number of available balls in the urn and thus the likelihood of drawing that color. Lets say I have three white (W) and three black (B) balls (my formula) or I have two white and two black balls. The likelihood should to draw {2W, 1B} should be different for the two szenario, don't you think?

So, the example urn contains three black and three white balls, from which we draw three balls such that we do not draw three of the same colour.   How do we enforce the rule, and what then is the probability distribution for drawing 1 or 2 black balls among the three drawn?

**Case 1:** Remove one ball from each (/both) colour until after the drawing is done.

$$\mathsf P(B=1\mid \text{case 1}) = \dfrac{\binom 21\binom 22}{\binom 43}\\ \mathsf P(B=2\mid \text{case 1}) = \dfrac{\binom 22\binom 21}{\binom 43}$$

**Case 2:** Whenever a third ball is drawn, put it aside and draw a replacement.

The event of drawing 1 black is then of actually drawing 1 black and 2 white, or of drawing 3 white and replacing the third. Likewise the complement.

$$\mathsf P(B=1\mid \text{case 2}) = \dfrac{\binom 31\binom 32+\binom 30\binom 33}{\binom 63}\\ \mathsf P(B=2\mid \text{case 2}) = \dfrac{\binom 33\binom 30+\binom 32\binom 31}{\binom 63}$$

**Case 3:** "Magically" prevent the forbidden outcomes without affecting the *relative* probabilities (the odds) between the other events.  That is: Use the definition for conditional probability.

$$\mathsf P(B=1\mid \text{case 3}) = \dfrac{\binom 31\binom 32}{\binom 31\binom 32+\binom 32\binom 31}\\ \mathsf P(B=2\mid \text{case 3}) = \dfrac{\binom 32\binom 31}{\binom 31\binom 32+\binom 32\binom 31}$$

Evaluate the results, or use binomial identities to show they are equal.

Comment: I wrote into the question how I restrict the drawing. In my computational experiments I redraw if I find a ball with a color I have drawn nearly all colors of already. I would think it makes it more likely to draw another red ball from an urn with two reds left instead of an urn with only one more red left. But then again, I would have removed all the "extra" ball from the other colors also. Is that where my mistake was - to not consider that the other balls would have been removed as well?

Comment: Yes, the key point is that there is no colour bias among the forbidden events; that your prohibition is *fair* and does not affect the *odds* between any of the remaining outcomes.